# Compress a string with zlib (deflate) and keep it in the memory

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

I started C ++ a few months ago, and tried to compress a piece of buffer with zlib, but instead of compressing it into a file using fopen / fwrite, I would like to compress the entire buffer into an char array and keep it in memory instead of writing to disk.
Here is my code at the moment:

```
int File::Write(const void *pBuffer,int nByte) {
    if (!m_pFile || !m_bWrite)
        return 0;

    m_Stream.next_in  = (Bytef*)pBuffer;
    m_Stream.avail_in = (uInt)nByte;

    int err = deflate(&m_Stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);

    while (m_Stream.avail_out == 0) {
        size_t nWritten = fwrite(m_Buffer,1,sizeof(m_Buffer),m_pFile);
        if(nWritten<sizeof(m_Buffer)) return 0;

        m_Stream.avail_out = sizeof(m_Buffer);
        m_Stream.next_out = m_Buffer;

        err = deflate(&m_Stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
    }

    return nByte;
}

bool File::Close() {
    int err;

    if(m_bWrite) {
        /* Finish the stream, still forcing small buffers: */
        for (;;) {
            err = deflate(&m_Stream, Z_FINISH);

            fwrite(m_Buffer, 1, sizeof(m_Buffer) - m_Stream.avail_out, m_pFile);
            m_Stream.avail_out = sizeof(m_Buffer);
            m_Stream.next_out = m_Buffer;

            if (err == Z_STREAM_END) break;
            CHECK_ERR(err, "deflate");
        }

        err = deflateEnd(&m_Stream);

        fclose(m_pFile);
        m_pFile = NULL;
    } else {
        err = inflateEnd(&m_Stream);

        fclose(m_pFile);
        m_pFile = NULL;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What, *specifically*, is the problem? If you run through their code deep enough, you'l find that zlib abstracts the IO subsystem through an overridable function table. You can stand up your own table of functions. Making a function set for in-memory IO rather than disk-based is fairly straight-forward, especially in C++.

Comment: Well, I'm actually trying to save the buffer in memory, replace fwrite with another function that saves the buffer in memory instead of the disk.

Comment: You have your data in memory already - in *m_Buffer*. Just copy it to another memory location (another buffer, big enough to hold all data)

Comment: I'm not seeing a `deflateInit()`.